# How to Post to twitter wall from my website

Tags: twitter

I'm building an application where users post their tips on various topics on my website.
While posting their tips - I've recently implemented the option where they can post that tip to their facebook wall as well.

They simply check the box - saying "Post to Facebook" and then the facebook pop-up opens up where they login and publish the tip to their facebook wall.

Now I want to add the new functionality where they can post it to their twitter feed as well directly from my website.

Are there any tutorials  that show how to implement this.
Thanks

Comment: Here's the twitter api in all its glory: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/

Comment: See the examples [here](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place to look for all things Twitter-API related: the [Twitter API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/). Also take a look at the [Twitter Dev Portal](http://dev.twitter.com/).