# Is there a way to generate tweets during application development?

Tags: java, twitter

I'm developing a web site that's going need to generate tweets. I have a twitter account, but don't want to post tweets to that account until the site is live, or a least, in beta. I tried creating a second account just for the purpose of posting during the development process, but twitter wants a mobile phone # that's different from the first account, so this approach wouldn't work unless I had a second phone.

Is there a standard way to make sure all the pieces are working together without posting test messages to the web site's main account during development?

EDIT:

To post tweets with the twitter API, you have to go to the app permissions page and switch to "Read and write." When you do this, it shows the error:

```
Error
You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before granting your application write capabilities.
Please read https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web for
more information
```

My mobile phone is already registered with the production account. To register it for the dev account, I'd have to de-register it for the main account. I'm trying to avoid that. I need to have both active so that both accounts can be used at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886693/how-to-post-to-twitter-wall-from-my-website

Comment: Well, I have code that tweets and it's working. I just want a mechanism for posting tweets that don't show in the main feed. So, I don't think it's a duplicate question.

Comment: Give this a read http://www.ragorder.com/twitter-test-account-testing-the-twitter-api-with-a-temporary-account/

Comment: @ug_ - That's a helpful post, thank you. However, I'm guessing that at the time you didn't have to use supply a phone number before enabling an app for posts.

Comment: @Branson yea your right.  So my solution is to either get a Skype phone number or go buy a burner phone from the gas station. Should only set you back about 20$.

Comment: +1 @ug_ - Both sound plausible. Thanks!

Comment: @DonBranson after a bit of looking theres also alot of services that provide "temporary" phone numbers for a small fee,  that might be a bit cheaper if you dont think you need the test account for a long timeframe. If you need it for the long haul for app maintenance then I think a burner phone with a solid phone number would be the way to go.

Comment: @ug_ If you wrap this up in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with Twitters mobile side phones to numbers are a one to one relationship. You will have to resort to getting a different phone number luckily there are some good options out there.

1. Get a Skype phone number. Its about 5$ per month but would probably be the easiest and cheapest solution.
2. If your like me and dont like lingering monthly bills attached to your credit card then you can go to almost any local gas station or store and buy a cheap phone and pay as you go plan. This will give you limited capabilities with this phone (no internet access unless you pay). But on the up side you would have a physical phone and number and no monthly bill to accidentally forget about for 3 years before you remember about it. I bought one a year or 2 ago after I dropped my phone in a river for a one time fee of about $40.

Comment: My son suggested using Google Voice. Works like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just to use an irregular phonenumber? For example 00000000. Twitter might not accept it, but it's atleast worth a try.

Comment: Twitter sends a text to confirm the phone number, so that won't work.

Comment: I'm not a Twitter user myself, but i just tried to register with a new email, and i didn't get prompted for a phone number at all, so just make an account from your computer :)

Comment: It will ask you for the phone number when you register your app.

Comment: Well, i'm assuming you only want to use this account while in beta, for debugging/testing, as you wrote, so couldn't you just acces the account from the computer while working on your project? Then you wouldn't have to register and should be able to continue your project unhindered.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide more information.

Comment: Looking at the link and the message provided in the error, it seems that's the only solution :/